# Update field from ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is there a way to update a field in a table from value already chosen in ssrs ?
I am looking to update a field year after choose the value in ssrs.

Comment: Why? Its not really what ssrs is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Nathan. However, you might be able to build a stored procedure and pass it a parameter from the report. The stored procedure would have an update statement that accepts your parameter as an input.

For example:

```
UPDATE Table
SET column = @parameter
```

You'll need to add a parameter to the SSRS report. If you build a stored procedure that accepts parameters they will show up in your report.

Comment: How can I pass a parameter from the report to a stored procedure ?

Comment: SP's are the same as your queries they are just stored as compiled queries on the server. Google is your friend: [Found this with a quick search](http://forums.asp.net/t/1471870.aspx)

Comment: @ShellNinja thanks , in the link that you've shared , it shows how call Strored Procedure in SSRS with Params , in my case I am looking how to pass params already chosen in ssrs into SP , how to do that ?

Comment: It's the same thing dude.

Comment: You may want to research how to use stored procedures with SSRS. It will make a lot more sense once you do.

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but wanted to provide an alternate solution if anyone runs across this question.  You could also place your update query within the stored procedure you're calling.  For example, if I wanted to update a field called DateReported prior to running my stored procedure to gather records, I could place it at the beginning of the stored procedure (before the select statement), and it would then execute prior.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it before report rendering. After that there is no way to call stored procedure. You can not add a custom event on the report to fire in case of a selection.